# Android edittext how we can know user entered either phone or email

Tags: android

[login activity]

i am new to android app development.
i am developing android app.
user can login using email id or mobile no.like facebook login.
how we can know either user entered email or mobile.
please help me.
For validation is their any validation frame work in android api like password,email id mobile no pattern matcher etc please help me.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etUserName"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:hint="Enter Email id/Mobile no"
    android:textColorHint="#4d060505"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="center">
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPwd"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="#4d060505"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUserName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

this code worked for me perfectly.
after your suggestions i tried it.

`if(isEmailValid(loginname)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(isValidMobileNumber(loginname)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mobileNo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Email or Mobile No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }`

Comment: as of your suggestions i modified my code and it worked perfectly for  me to find given input is email or mobile number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try for Email

```
boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
 return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

if your`Edittext` value return true than its Email else Mobile number

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to check whether the input is an email or not:

```
 public static boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By These two methods I solved this problem

```
public static boolean isPhoneNumberValid(String phoneNoWithConCode, String countryCode)
    {
        PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        try
        {
            Phonenumber.PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNoWithConCode, countryCode);
            return phoneUtil.isValidNumber(numberProto);
        }
        catch (NumberParseException e)
        {
            System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }

public static boolean isEmailValid(String email){
    return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

call these two methods one by one like

```
if(isPhoneNumberValid(.. , ..))
{
   //write your mobile no logic here
}else if(isEmailValid(..)
{
  //write you email logic here
}
```

Comment: currently, this code is not working for Indian mobile number start with 6 like this no 62675XXXXX

Answer (score 0):

First of all `getText` from `editText` and set proper validations for checking email and mobile number like below:

```
  email=edt_email.getText().toString();
  if (!isValidEmail(email)) 
  {
        // your code
  }

  private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    private boolean isValidPhone(String pass) {
        return pass != null && pass.length() == 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here are what I use in my project

```
private static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String mobile) {
        String regEx = "^[0-9]{11,12}$";
        return mobile.matches(regEx);
    }

private boolean isValidEmaillId(String email){

        return Pattern.compile("^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$").matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

you can use if else logic to it to validate mobile or email in your activity